# Splitting a multi year contract row into multiple rows covering 1 year/365 days from start to end date

Tags: sql, python-3.x, sql-server

I have contract no 1 covering from 8/1/2022 to 7/31/2024, I need all the active contracts to split into multiple rows covering 365 days/year per row.
Existing table - EX- contract 1 is from 8/1/2022 to 7/31/2024,
I need contract 1 to be split from 8/1/2022 to 7/31/2023 in row1 and in ro2 contract 1 to be split from 8/1/2023 to 7/31/2024(2nd year of contract) like wise third year in row3 from 8/1/2024 to 7/31/2025.

| Contract | start_date | End_date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 8/1/2022 | 7/31/2024 |
| 23 | 8/7/2022 | 8/8/2023 |
| 26 | 6/8/2022 | 6/9/2025 |

I need above table to split like

| S.No | Contract | start_date | End_date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 8/1/2022 | 7/31/2023 |
| 2 | 1 | 8/1/2023 | 7/31/2024 |
| 3 | 23 | 8/7/2022 | 8/8/2023 |
| 4 | 26 | 6/8/2022 | 6/7/2023 |
| 5 | 26 | 6/8/2023 | 6/7/2024 |
| 6 | 26 | 6/8/2024 | 6/7/2025 |

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

Comment: *I need...* is not an actual question, it just lets people know you haven't bothered to try anything and expect code for free. Please include your current attempt and explain what is not working. [No attempt made](https://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/).

Comment: It looks like we night need some more information to understand what your end goal is. I understand that you have the “raw data” with contracts and start/end for these. Do you need to create a new table with the number of active contracts for each period? Would be nice if your question/example would elaborate more on what you are trying to the as the examples are not super clear.

Comment: I am voting to reopen this question because it is a tricky topic to know how to search for if you don't know the proper terminology. They did provide sample data and desired output which is the basic requirement for getting help with a question here. Not only should this not be closed I have an answer ready if we can reopen it.

Comment: I'd vote to reopen if OP reworded such that they are asking for help as opposed to "I need".

Comment: This should be a relatively straight forward select with a cross-apply to a generated calendar generator sub-query.

Answer (score 1):

The following will determine the maximum possible years for any contract, generate a sequence of numbers 0..N, calculate each potential full-year for each contract, and then trim the results to reflect the actual contract end-date.

```
-- Upper bound on number of years
DECLARE @MaxYears INT = (
    SELECT 1 + MAX(DATEDIFF(year, Start_date, End_date))
    FROM COntracts
)

;WITH NumTable AS (
    SELECT 0 AS N
    UNION ALL
    SELECT N + 1
    FROM NumTable
    WHERE N < @Maxyears
)
SELECT
    C.Contract,
    D.Start_Date,
    CASE WHEN D.End_date < C.End_date THEN D.End_date ELSE C.End_date END AS End_date
FROM Contracts C
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT
        DATEADD(year, N.N, C.Start_date) AS Start_date,
        DATEADD(day, -1, DATEADD(year, N.N + 1, C.Start_date)) AS End_date
    FROM NumTable N
) D
WHERE D.Start_date <= C.End_date
ORDER BY C.Contract, D.Start_Date
```

If using SQL Server 2022, the NumTable CTE can be replaced with a `GENERATE_SERIES()` function, and the `CASE` expression can be replaced with `LEAST()`.

```
SELECT C.Contract, D.Start_Date, LEAST(D.End_date, C.End_date) AS End_date
FROM Contracts C
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT
        DATEADD(year, S.Value, C.Start_date) AS Start_date,
        DATEADD(day, -1, DATEADD(year, S.Value + 1, C.Start_date)) AS End_date
    FROM GENERATE_SERIES(0, DATEDIFF(year, C.Start_date, C.End_date)) S
) D
WHERE D.Start_date <= C.End_date
ORDER BY C.Contract, D.Start_Date
```

Results:

| Contract | Start_Date | End_date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-08-01 | 2023-07-31 |
| 1 | 2023-08-01 | 2024-07-31 |
| 23 | 2022-08-07 | 2023-08-06 |
| 23 | 2023-08-07 | 2023-08-08 |
| 26 | 2022-06-08 | 2023-06-07 |
| 26 | 2023-06-08 | 2024-06-07 |
| 26 | 2024-06-08 | 2025-06-07 |
| 26 | 2025-06-08 | 2025-06-09 |

The above is slightly different from OP requested results, but I believe this to be correct based on the stated requirements.

See [this db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/6qvJ7f4f).

**Edge case:** If a contract starts on 29 February of a leap year, the calculations will define the start if each following year as either the 28th or 29th with a potential for a later contract year having a 366 day period from 28 February through 28 February of a later leap year.

Answer (score 0):

You may try the following recursive CTE:

```
with cte as
(
  select Contract, start_date sd, end_date ed, DATEADD(year, 1, start_date) new_ed
  from table_name
  where end_date >= GETDATE() -- get only active contracts
  union all
  select Contract, new_ed, ed, DATEADD(year, 1, new_ed)
  from cte
  where new_ed < DATEADD(day, -1, ed)
)
select ROW_NUMBER() over (order by Contract, sd) [S.No],
       Contract,
       sd start_date,
       iif(YEAR(ed) = YEAR(new_ed), ed, DATEADD(day, -1, new_ed)) end_date
from cte
order by Contract, sd
```

[See demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/FVdYE7jO)

Comment: You are welcome, could you accept this answer by clicking the green checkmark so others can see that your problem has been resolved.